# online events and geolocation

Tags: civievent

Given the current world situation, everyone is moving towards online events.  We used to host events in different countries and charge in local currency.

Now that we are offering online events, we might get people from different countries.  How can I have a multi currency event?  One way I thought I could do this was to create different events with different currencies based on the targeted countries, but only show the event on the list based on the geolocation of the user.  Is this anyway possible,  Can anyone think of a workaround for this??

Most countries would be charged in US dolars, but only one or two would be in local currency, so it is really an exception rather than the rule.

I am open to any ideas out there.

Comment: this may not be a helpful answer for your situation, but in case others read it and are using Drupal then you can do a Drupal Webform that allows for payments in different currencies, but you then need to also do a Formula field and apply the relevant exchange rates. or you could have a different webform per 'odd case' country and direct folk to that if they want to pay in local.